# How do I get phone numbers from file in correct format using awk? Working script needs tweaking

Tags: awk, scripting

These are the files:

project2.phone:

```
  Dave,7348389800
  Barry,3131234567
  Carl,2483445576
  Marci,3134491390
  Tom,2484962204
  Alden,6165564458
```

project2.day:

```
  Barry,tuesday
  Carl,friday
  Tom,sunday
  Alden,wednesday
  Dave,thursday
  Marci,saturday
```

My output looks like this:

```
Day            Name         Phone
 ____________________________________
SUNDAY         Tom       2484962204
MONDAY         Nobody
TUESDAY        Barry     3131234567
WEDNESDAY      Alden     6165564458
THURSDAY       Dave      7348389800
FRIDAY         Carl      2483445576
SATURDAY       Marci     3134491390
SUNDAY         Tom       2484962204
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
Day            Name         Phone
 ____________________________________
SUNDAY         Tom      (248)496-2204
MONDAY         Nobody
TUESDAY        Barry    (313)123-4567
WEDNESDAY      Alden    (616)556-4458
THURSDAY       Dave     (734)838-9800
FRIDAY         Carl     (248)344-5576
SATURDAY       Marci    (313)449-1390
SUNDAY         Tom      (248)496-2204
```

---

I can not get the phone numbers in correct format.

It only works when I use **awk -F, -f project2.ksh project2.phone project2.day**.

I need to be able to run ksh project2.ksh to get the output.

This is the script:

**project2.ksh**

---

```
      BEGIN     { split("SUNDAY;MONDAY;TUESDAY;WEDNESDAY;THURSDAY;FRIDAY;SATURDAY", week, ";") }


      FNR == NR { name2phone[$1] = gensub(/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})(.*)/, "(\\1) \\2-\\3", "g", $2 )
        next
      }

      { day2name[toupper($2)] = $1 }

           END       { fmtstr= "%-10s\t%s\t%s\n"

                         printf(fmtstr,"Day","Name","Phone")

                         print "____________________________________"

                     for(d=1;d< length(week); d++ )
                     {

                         cname = (week[d] in day2name ) ? day2name[ week[d] ] : "NOBODY"

                         printf( fmtstr, week[d], cname, name2phone[ cname])
                     }
      }
```

Comment: This is for a school project I need to follow guidelines very closely. Just trying to finish this script up. Help is appreciated.

Comment: What you have is not a `ksh` script, it _is_ an `awk` script.

Comment: Yeah I realize that now but I was told you would be able to put awk -F, -f project2.ksh project2.phone project2.day in the korn shell script . Either way the real important part is the phone number formatting being correct. I can use awk to capture the output that should be okay.

Comment: I can get it to work I just need help to format the phone numbers correctly. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas with GNU awk:

```
$ awk '{match($0,/(...)(...)(.*)/,a);printf("(%s)%s-%s\n",a[1],a[2],a[3])}' <<<"333456789"
(333)456-789

$ awk '{match($0,/(...)(...)(.*)/,arr);printf( "(" arr[1] ")" arr[2] "-" arr[3])}' <<<"333456789"
(333)456-789

$ awk '{a=$0;printf("(%s)%s-%s\n",substr(a,1,3),substr(a,4,3), substr(a,7))}' <<<"333456789"
(333)456-789
```

To adapt it to your script try this one:

Replacing your last script line:

```
printf( fmtstr, week[d], cname, name2phone[ cname])
```

With bellow, should work ok:

```
ph=name2phone[ cname];
match(ph,/(...)(...)(.*)/,arr);
printf( fmtstr, week[d], cname, "(" arr[1] ")" arr[2] "-" arr[3])
```

Comment: I am sure this would work in the command prompt. But I need the number formatting in my script.

Comment: @Jaruto See update

Comment: Sir. You are a life saver. Thank you so much!! Are you Romanian?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  raw=$3; //or whichever column the phone# is in
  area=substr(raw,1,3);
  prefix=substr(raw,4,3);
  suffix=substr(raw,7);
  print $1, $2, "("area")"prefix"-"suffix 
}
```

works for me

Comment: How do I get it to print into the correct column?  The print statement puts it in the first column. If you could look at my code I made raw=name2phone[cname] and it formatted the numbers correctly. Now I just need them in the right spot.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F, -lane '

@ARGV and $Phone_of{$F[0]} = $F[1] =~ s/(...)(...)(.*)/($1)$2-$3/r;

@ARGV or $Person_of{uc $F[1]} = $F[0];

END {
   $fmt = join "\t", map { qq/%${_}s/ } qw/ -10 1 1 /;
   print sprintf $fmt, qw/ Day Name Phone /;
   print "_" x 37;
   for my $day ( map { uc($_ . day) } qw/ sun mon tues wednes thurs fri satur / ) {
      print sprintf $fmt, $day, $Person_of{$day} || "Nobody", $Phone_of{$Person_of{$day}};
   }
}

' project2.phone project2.day
```

We first fillup the hash `%Phone_of` with keys as names and values their phone numbers. Next, when `@ARGV` has gone zero, i.e., the last file (.day) is being processed, we populate the hash `%Person_of` with keys as uppercase day and value as person working on that day.

In the `END{...}` block, when both the files have been processed away, we first setup the format string and using that print the header. Finally, we loop over the days of the week (uppercased) and display the day, person working on that day (or nobody if nobody's working on that day), and the phone number of the person.

## Result:

```
Day             Name    Phone
_____________________________________
SUNDAY          Tom     (248)496-2204
MONDAY          Nobody
TUESDAY         Barry   (313)123-4567
WEDNESDAY       Alden   (616)556-4458
THURSDAY        Dave    (734)838-9800
FRIDAY          Carl    (248)344-5576
SATURDAY        Marci   (313)449-1390
```

## Caveats

```
No whitespace(s) in the input files (*.phone, *.day)
```